# What are the linguistic/historical reason of different conjugation of modal verbs?

Tags: conjugation, modal-verb

I'd like to know whether any deep reason exists why conjugations for *ich* and *er,sie,es* are the same.

Comment: Excellent question. The keyword is _preterite-presents_.

Comment: @Chris Just understood that the same thing is in English=)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most of the modal verbs are so-called *preterite-presents* (*Präteritopräsentien*). A demonstrative example is the German verb **wissen** (though commonly not counted as modal). "Regular" verbs have an *-e* ending in the first person singular present and a *-t* ending in the third person singular present.

> ich geh**e**, er geh**t**.

However, the verb **wissen** has

> ich weiß, er weiß

without the expected endings. The reason for this is that once the current present forms of **wissen** were past forms. You might know that in past tense of strong verbs, the first person und third person singular have no endings; e.g. in

> ich ging, er ging.

So the current present tense of the preterite-presents were past tense forms in Indo-European or early Germanic times.
Coming back to the verb **wissen**, we can notice that this German verb is related to the latin verb **videre**, *to see*. So **ich weiß** once had the meaning of **ich sah/habe gesehen**. If you have seen something, then you know it. So it was possible for the past tense form to gain a present tense meaning.
Most of the other modal verbs have a similar history with a tense shift.

Additionally, you might notice that the modal verbs of the English language take no *-s* in the present tense third person singular (*he can*, not *he cans*). The reason for this is the same: These present tense forms once were past tense forms.

<sup>I have simplified things here: I have treated current forms like *ich weiß* as if they were the forms as found in older stages of languages. That's of course not true, but there have been several sound changes. However, these sound changes were regular so that the first person and third person forms evolved parallelly to yield *ich weiß* and *er weiß*.</sup>

Comment: that's awesome. Thanks! If only grammar books for mere mortals were of such kind...

Comment: This is awesome, indeed. Where did you learn this?

Comment: @Grantwalzer: _Preterite-presents_ are/should be treated in every major book of historical linguistics of German or English (or Indo-European languages in general).

Comment: @Grantwalzer: It is on Wikipedia, and one just has to remember a beautiful word like Präteritopräsentia.

Comment: @Veredomon Your comment makes "Präteritopräsentia/en" appear like an everyday, easy-to-remember word, which it isn't. And that it's on Wikipedia doesn't answer my question in any way.